# Calling json inside Mako Template without for loops

Tags: python, templates, cherrypy, mako

im trying to figure out how to call something from a json file without using for loops.

```
% for projekte in liste:
        <tr>
            <td>${projekte['id']}</td>
            <td>${projekte['projektnummer']}</td>
            <td>${projekte['bezeichnung']}</td>
            <td>${projekte['beschreibung']}</td>
            <td>${projekte['bearbeitungszeitraumA']} bis ${projekte['bearbeitungszeitraumB']}</td>
            <td>${projekte['budget']}</td>
            <td>${projekte['kundenverweis']}</td>
            <td>${projekte['mitarbeiterverweis']}</td>
            <td>${projekte['aufwand']}</td>
            <td>
                <ul class="buttons">
                    <li><a href="edit?key=${projekte['id']}">Bearbeiten</a></li>
                    <li><a href="delete?key=${projekte['id']}">Löschen</a></li>
                    % for orga in liste3:
                        <li><a href="/orga/edit?key=${orga['id']}">${orga['bezeichnung']}</a></li>
                    % endfor
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    % endfor
```

orga has id's of the projects. The issue is that i cant figure out how to inluce them without a loop because this one will give me a link for every project i have inside very single entry.
I want it to send me to another form with the projects ID to continue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not going through its keys ?

```
% for projekte in liste:
   <%
    # instead of looping on `liste3` variable until you find the match
    # extract the match directly.
    # if not found - value is None by default
    orga = liste3.get(projekte['id'])
   %>
   <tr>      
      % for key, value in projekte.items():
        <td> ${value} </td>

        % if orga:
        <li>
            <a href="/orga/edit?key=${orga['id']}">
                ${orga['bezeichnung']}
            </a>
        </li>
        % endif

      % endfor
   </tr>
%endfor
```

A side note regarding the `<td>`s:
The `for key,value`  can be replaced with the following if you care about the order of the rows/values

```
sort_by = ['id', 'projektnummer', 'bezeichnung' ...]

% for key in sort_by:
   <td> ${projekte[key]} </td>
% endfor
```

OR, if you care about the order, make sure to initialize `projekte` as `projekte = OrderedDict()` vs `projekte = {}` it will keep its order during insertion of values / keys ... also when printing ...

Answer (score 0):

didnt find an answer so i used a workaround:

```
% for projekte in liste:
            <tr>
                %for orga in liste3:

                    %if orga['id'] == projekte['id']:
                        ## do stuff
                    %endif
                 %endfor
             </tr>
%endfor
```

its ineffictient but works
basically iterating through the whole list and checking ids. if they match then it does something